# Disabling autocommands for help buffers

Tags: vim

I have the following lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
" UNIX fileformat
au BufRead,BufNewFile * set fileformats=unix,dos
au BufRead,BufNewFile * set fileformat=unix
```

These are to make any opened file using the unix file format.

It works well in almost all cases except for the help messages. If I type, let's say:

```
:h help
```

Vim first complains that:

```
"helphelp.txt" [readonly] 350L, 13662C Error detected while processing
BufRead Auto commands for "*": E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable'
is off: fileformat=unix
```

Obviously, I am trying to set the fileformat option on a non-modifiable buffer so this error is to be expected. However, what is the cleanest way to get rid of it without removing the feature for other files ?

Is there a way to conditionally apply/not apply autocommands for the help buffers ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'fileformats'` is a global setting, it should suffice to set it only once in your .vimrc:

```
set fileformats=unix,dos
```

The error will occur for any other unmodifiable file, not just help files. Therefore, it's best to make the setting conditional on the `'modifiable'` buffer setting:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile * if &l:modifiable | setlocal fileformat=unix | endif
```

(Alternatively, you could also just `:silent!` the error, but I regard the conditional as cleaner.)